# Verifying linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

P= vector space that consists of polynomials of degree <=2. 
X:P->P is defined as X(f(x))= f(x) - f'(x)

Verify that X is a linear transformation .

Can anyone help with this.

Comment: I suppose $f'$ means the first derivative?

Comment: Yes. @Tortuga.A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if $f'$ is the first derivative of $f$. Then in order to check if $X$ is linear, we have to check the following 2 things: (I omitted $(x)$ just for simplicity)

1. If $X(f+g)=X(f)+X(g)$? This is easy to check since by the definition of $X$, we have 
   \begin{align}
   X(f+g)&=(f+g)+(f'+g')\\
         &=(f+f')+(g+g')\quad (by\ re-arranging)\\
         &=X(f)+X(g)
   \end{align}
   So our first argument holds based on our calculation
2. Then we need to show if $X(cf)=cX(f)$ for some scalar $c$? The method is very similar to the proof of part 1, and I will leave it to you.

Ask me again if the 2nd step does not clear to you or you want me to help you check you answer.

Comment: X(cf)=(cf) - (cf')
        = c(f - f')
        = cX(f) 
@Tortuga.A

Comment: bingo! But to be more precise, we actually have $X(cf)=(cf) - (cf)'$, which is $X(cf)=(cf) - c(f')$ since derivative is linear. Anyway you are correct.

Comment: Thank You!

Although the question is solved, I faced a problem with another question but would like to apply to it. 

If C be consisting of the basis of polynomials 1,x, and x^2. Then compute the matrix [X]C

How would this be solved. @Tortuga.A

Comment: You know what $X$ does to a polynomials $f$, so you can find what $X(1), X(x),X(x^2)$ are, and then you can write them as a linear combination of the basis $\{1,x,x^2\}$, and then you will get your matrix.

Comment: So
X(1)=1,
X(x)=x+1,
X(x^2)=x^2 +2x

How would write this as a combination?

Comment: So $C$ is the vector space with basis $\{1,x,x^2\}$, then if you denote the basis by $\{a,b,c\}$, where $a=1,b=x,c=x^2$. Then you can see that $X(1)=a,\ X(2)=a+b, X(3)=2b+c$(this is called a linear combination of basis). So the matrix should be?

Comment: \begin{1 0 0
1 1 0
0 2 1}

Comment: you mean \begin{pmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&2\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}?

Comment: Just shift the rows and columns.

Comment: Well, I believe you should NOT shift the rows and columns.

Comment: Got a little confused. Understood. This will be the final matrix.

Comment: Right, this would the final matrix :) (and in fact you can check this matrix does exactly the same things as your linear transformation $X$ does)

Answer (score 0):

$P$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, so, to prove that the transformation $T(f(x))=f(x)+f'(x)$ is linear you have to prove that:

> $\forall \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\forall f, g \in P$ we have
>   $
> T(f+\alpha g)=T(f)+\alpha T(g)
> $

To do this write the transformation and use the linearity of derivative:
$$
T(f+\alpha g)=(f+\alpha g)+(f+\alpha g)'=f+ \alpha g +f'+\alpha g'= f+\alpha f' + g+\alpha g' =T(f)+\alpha T(g)
$$